# Recurrence equation from an infinite Fourier series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation, fourier-analysis

Consider the following set of equations 
$$
\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \left[ \psi_k(\lambda) \left(  \lambda I_k'(\lambda R) \cos k\phi \cos \phi + \frac{k}{R}  I_k(\lambda R) \sin k\phi \sin \phi \right) + f_1 (\lambda,k) \cos k \phi \right]  = 0 \, , \\
\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \left[ \psi_k(\lambda) \left(  \lambda I_k'(\lambda R) \cos k\phi \sin \phi - \frac{k}{R} I_k(\lambda R) \sin k\phi \cos \phi \right) + f_2 (\lambda,k) \sin k \phi \right]  = 0 \, , 
$$
where $I_k$ is the modified Bessel function and $\psi_k(\lambda)$ is a real function of the variable $\lambda$.
Here $f_1$ and $f_2$ are two real functions and $R>0$.
Prime denotes derivative with respect to the argument.
My goal is to rearrange and equate the Fourier coefficients in order to get a recurrence equation (i.e. the summation sign should disappear.)
It would be great if someone could provide with useful ideas that help.
Thanks. Best

r

Comment: This equation has been derived in "Stokes flow due to a Stokeslet in a pipe", J. Fluid Mech. (1978), vol. 86, part 4, pp. 727-744 by Liron and Shahar.

Comment: A more simplified equations can already be obtained by setting $\lambda I_k' (\lambda R) = \lambda I_{k+1} (\lambda R) + \frac{k}{R} I_k(\lambda R)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the idea is quite simple. All what you need is to to apply the following trigonometric relations
$$
\cos k\phi \cos \phi = \frac{1}{2} \left( \cos((k-1)\phi) + \cos((k+1)\phi) \right) \, , \\
\sin k\phi \sin \phi = \frac{1}{2} \left( \cos((k-1)\phi) - \cos((k+1)\phi) \right) \, , 
$$
and 
$$
\cos k\phi \sin \phi = \frac{1}{2} \left( \sin((k+1)\phi) - \sin((k-1)\phi) \right) \, , \\
\sin k\phi \cos \phi = \frac{1}{2} \left( \sin((k+1)\phi) + \sin((k-1)\phi) \right) \, .
$$

Then try to express the first equation based on $\cos k\phi$ and the second equation on $\sin k\phi$. 
I.e. make the change of summation index $k$ accordingly to obtain the following equations
$$
\frac{\lambda}{2} I_k (\lambda R) \psi_{k+1} (\lambda) + \frac{\lambda}{2} I_k (\lambda R) \psi_{k-1} (\lambda) + f_1 (\lambda, k) = 0 \, , \\
-\frac{\lambda}{2} I_k (\lambda R) \psi_{k+1} (\lambda) + \frac{\lambda}{2} I_k (\lambda R) \psi_{k-1} (\lambda) + f_2 (\lambda, k) = 0 \, ,
$$
which leads immediately to 
$$
\lambda I_{k+1}(\lambda R) \psi_{k} = -(f_1(\lambda,k) + f_2(\lambda,k)) \, , \\
\lambda I_{k-1}(\lambda R) \psi_k = -(f_1(\lambda,k) - f_2(\lambda,k)) \, .
$$

Cheers